How can I disable the wifi driver on an Intel Mac running Sonoma?
I need to use my Mac for an open-book exam. This does not allow internet access. I would like to know a way to permanently disable the wifi driver on Intel Mac running the latest OS (Sonoma).
Disable wireless network card Mac OS X suggests: "You can move the IO80211Family.kext from /System/Library/Extensions." But when I run the mv command, it says "operation not successful". This occurs even after running csrutil disable in recovery mode. I simply do not have access to this.
Is there a way?

I am not an expert in this - but it may be possible to do this with a MDM profile that only allow wifi in whitelist. You may also try removing it after you also disable AMFI(apple mobile file integrity). It is not possible to permanently disable wifi, we can only restrict it from non-root users

Why is disabling WiFI in Settings not enough?

Yes: Surely just turning off Wifi is good enough? If not, you should ask the exam board for methods that they are prepared to accept. I doubt you can remove the driver now, because the OS cannot be modified anymore.

Conversely, perhaps the testing location could disable WiFi, (or perhaps temporarily password-protect the SSID if it is presently open and unsecured,) prohibiting you from connecting. There is not enough information about the WiFi setup at the testing location here to give a good answer.

In recent versions of macOS, the /System volume is protected in a way which can't be disabled by csrutil. So, the solution from 2014 won't work any longer.
Alternatives:

Just disable WiFi in System Settings
Make your Mac forget the school WiFi and remove its password from the Keychain

PS: Ideally, the school/university should ensure that the exam rules are followed.
